# Invoke .bat file from ruby script

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Please help me invoke a .bat file from ruby script. I tried the following. My test.rb file given below:

```
batch "run-script" do
  cwd 'D:\\jenkins\jobs\HybrisJob\workspace'
  code <<-EOH
    `hybrisserver.bat`
  EOH
  action :run
end
```

but it is not working.

```
[2015-03-19T14:01:16+05:30] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: batch[run-script] ((chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe) line 1) had an error:
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try using ruby code in a batch resource, it launch a cmd.exe, which has no clue of backticks or system command.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.chef.io/resource_batch.html#examples)

```
batch "run-script" do
  cwd 'D:\\jenkins\\jobs\\HybrisJob\\workspace'
  code "hybrisserver.bat"
  action :run
end
```

Escape all `\` in your cwd attribute (or use `/` the resource will take care of changing it to system separator)
There's no need to use Heredoc syntax for a single line with no args nor other lines of script testing the return.

Comment: so is cwd resource not available for chef-recipe? I tried this `cwd 'D://jenkins/jobs/HybrisJob/workspace' `
system('hybrisserver.bat') and getting error `FATAL: NoMethodError: No resource or method named `cwd' for `Chef::Recipe``

Comment: cwd is an attribute to the batch resource to tell it where to start the cmd.exe. there's no cwd resource. See my answer, it's the corrected batch resource from your question. Running ruby commands in the recipe is not recomended